# Unable to make property of custom control visible in designer

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

namespace Tools
{
    [ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.All)]
    public class ToolStripNumericUpDown : CustomToolStripControlHost
    {
        private NumericUpDown nud;

        public ToolStripNumericUpDown()
            : base(new NumericUpDown())
        {
            this.nud = this.Control as NumericUpDown;


        }

        [Description("The number of decimal places"),
        Category("Custom"),
        EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
        Browsable(true),
        DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible),
        Bindable(true),
        DefaultValue(2)]
        public int DecimalPlaces
        {
            get { return nud.DecimalPlaces; }
            set { nud.DecimalPlaces = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnSubscribeControlEvents(Control control)
        {
            base.OnSubscribeControlEvents(control);
            //Add your code here to subscribe Control Events
        }

        protected override void OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(Control control)
        {
            base.OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(control);
            //Add your code here to unsubscribe control events.
        }
    }
}
```

and in a separate file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

namespace System.Windows.Forms
{
    //[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.All)]
    public class CustomToolStripControlHost : ToolStripControlHost
    {
        public CustomToolStripControlHost()
            : base(new Control())
        {
        }

        public CustomToolStripControlHost(Control c)
            : base(c)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

But the `DecimalPlaces` property refuses to show up in the designer, despite rebuilding the project, closing and reopening the designer etc. Can anyone shed any light on this?

I'm using VS 2013 Community, targeting .NET 4.

Thanks

EDIT: To clarify, I mean that the property doesn't show up in VS designer's property grid when I add my `ToolstripNumericUpDown` to a `ContextMenuStrip` - in fact, clicking on my control makes no changes to the property grid at all; the property grid still shows the properties from the previously selected control.

EDIT 2: The plot thickens. If I select the control's parent ToolStripMenuItem, then access that's DropDownItems, I can see my control and I can see and edit all it's properties.

Comment: Just a sanity check, have you compiled the project since you made those changes? I'm not exactly sure on the details, but the designer uses the latest compiled version of custom controls, so changing a custom control requires you to compile before you can use those changes in the designer.

Comment: Yes, as stated I've rebuilt it, closed the designer and re-opened it. Even tried closing and reopening VS completely.

Answer (score 0):

The Control is generic class, to show the decimalplaces you need to make a typecast to convert the Control to the specific type (NumericUpDown).

Below code will work:

```
public CustomToolStripControlHost(Control c)
        : base(c)
    {
        NumericUpDown numUpDown = (NumericUpDown)c;
        numUpDown.DecimalPlaces = 10;
    }
```

Comment: This hasn't made any difference.

Comment: Also I don't see how this would expose the property in the designer? This looks like it's just setting the number of decimal places in code...